# Groupby on columns with overlapping groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

Continuing from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656455/aggregations-over-specific-columns-of-a-large-dataframe-with-named-output).

This produces a dafatrame with 81 columns and filled with random numbers:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np

col = "A,B,C".split(',')
col1 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9".split(',')
col2 = "E,F,G".split(',')

all_dims = [col, col1, col2]
all_keys = ['.'.join(i) for i in itertools.product(*all_dims)]
rng = pd.date_range(end=pd.Timestamp.today().date(), periods=12, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(len(rng), len(all_keys))), columns=all_keys, index=rng)
```

A dataframe with these 81 columns names:

```
 ['A.1.E', 'A.1.F', 'A.1.G', 'A.2.E', 'A.2.F', 'A.2.G', 'A.3.E', 'A.3.F', 'A.3.G', 'A.4.E', 
'A.4.F', 'A.4.G', 'A.5.E', 'A.5.F', 'A.5.G', 'A.6.E','A.6.F', 'A.6.G', 'A.7.E', 'A.7.F', 
'A.7.G', 'A.8.E', 'A.8.F', 'A.8.G', 'A.9.E', 'A.9.F', 'A.9.G', 'B.1.E', 'B.1.F', 'B.1.G', 
'B.2.E', 'B.2.F', 'B.2.G', 'B.3.E', 'B.3.F', 'B.3.G', 'B.4.E', 'B.4.F', 'B.4.G', 'B.5.E', 
'B.5.F', 'B.5.G', 'B.6.E', 'B.6.F', 'B.6.G', 'B.7.E', 'B.7.F', 'B.7.G', 'B.8.E', 'B.8.F', 
'B.8.G', 'B.9.E', 'B.9.F', 'B.9.G', 'C.1.E', 'C.1.F', 'C.1.G', 'C.2.E', 'C.2.F', 'C.2.G', 
'C.3.E', 'C.3.F', 'C.3.G', 'C.4.E', 'C.4.F', 'C.4.G', 'C.5.E', 'C.5.F', 'C.5.G', 'C.6.E', 
'C.6.F', 'C.6.G', 'C.7.E', 'C.7.F', 'C.7.G', 'C.8.E', 'C.8.F', 'C.8.G', 'C.9.E', 'C.9.F','C.9.G']
```

Using the solution from my previous question I know how to make a grouper function that for example takes all 'A.*.E' columns (that have any number in the middle), sums them and produces a named output column called 'A.SUM.E'. And then does the same for 'A.*.F', 'A.*.G' and so on:

```
def grouper(col):
    c = col.split('.')
    return f'{c[0]}.SUM.{c[-1]}'

df.groupby(grouper, axis=1).sum()
```

My question is can a function be written in a way to produce overlapping groups also? For example, can a grouper be made that produces a SUM1 for ('A.1.E' + 'A.2.E') and a SUM2 for ('A.1.E' + 'A.3.E'), so the column 'A.1.E' would appear in both sums.

Comment: What have you tried _yourself_ so far? I think your question has a very easy and straightforward answer. Chances are good, that you find a solution yourself, if you just take half an hour to try something.

Comment: @jottbe I've tried passing in a dictionary with the mappings but a dictionary by definition has only unique keys, so I cannot assign one column to multiple groups.

Comment: @jottbe Also all the questions I saw on this topic never received a solution, so it seems not too straightforward :)

Comment: Hmmm, are you _really_ sure? I guess you can manage to sum up one field on it's own, can't you? Sorry for my reaction, but it seems a bit, as if you let the stackoverflow community program your whole solutions. After one question is answered you come up almost immediately with the next question to solve the next bit of logic.

Comment: @jottbe Well, the person who answered my previous question just added a comment on it that it is not possible to have the same column in different groups. So I am a bit skeptical you have an easy solution to this, but by all means, feel free to post something ;)

Comment: Surely not, because I don't like the feeling to be exploited. But thanks for your offer.

Comment: Dear @delica. First point, if you really intend to get your problem solved, you should describe, what you want. You said you wanted to add overlaping sums, but didn't really specify how they overlap. If you just want to have the sums of the columns in your example, it is embarrasingly simple to do that. Second, if you come up with the next question only a few hours after the last was answered it might be a good idea to pay someone doing the job. If I answer questions here I usually do it in a detailed way and spend a lot of time doing it.

Comment: But from time to time I get the impression, that some people here exploit the community and just save money in letting others do their job. Sorry if that doesn't apply to you, but I got that suspicion.

Comment: @jottbe I wrote an example showing exactly what I needed. I also reported your posts for being rude and condescending. I am sorry again but this is not okay what you are doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be possible with groupby as any given column can only be in one group, not in multiple groups.
To solve this case you can modify my first solution to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57657779/3944322):

```
cols = sorted([(x[0],x[1]) for x in set([(x.split('.')[0], x.split('.')[-1]) for x in df.columns])])
for c0,c1 in cols:
    for n in range(2,10):
        df[f'{c0}.SUM{n}.{c1}'] = df.filter(regex = f'{c0}\.(1|{n})\.{c1}').sum(axis=1)
```

(This will work for single-digit numbers (1 through 9) in the column headers as per your example. If there are numbers > 9 you'll have to modify the regex accordingly.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer Stef! I will wait for a bit to see any other before accepting. Also from my research it seems to be not possible with groupby but maybe someone out there has found a way.

Comment: It seems you are the only one with an answer :)  I actually also solved this with a loop and with a filter (also possible with just selecting by column name), but I am a bit disappointed that groupby does not support this. I did make a feature request on the pandas issues tracker so will see how that goes. Thank you - really appreciate your help!